# why the transmission settings reset to default when restarted

Tags: linux

Now I am editing the transmission config `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`, I changed the configuration and restart the transmission deamon:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl restart transmission-daemon
```

The setting I have changed was reset to default, all my changes are lost. why would this could happen? what should I do to modify the transmision config?

Answer (score 4):

Yo should stop the transmission daemon (`sudo service transmission-daemon stop`) before doing any changes on the settings.json file

More detailed info [here](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/MovedToGitHub/EditConfigFiles)